# MySQL Conditions from Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to calculate a table using a `SELECT` statement. I have a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
AgentID     |      Date      |  Incurred     |    FallOffDate
==============================================================
kegomez     |   2012-11-19   |     2.0       |    2013-11-19
kegomez     |   2012-11-24   |     0.5       |    2013-11-24
kegomez     |   2013-01-21   |     2.0       |    2014-01-21
kegomez     |   2013-08-18   |     2.0       |    2014-08-18
```

I was trying to do the calculations on during the select and possibly create a view but have no luck so far. In the end the table will look like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
AgentID     |      Date      |  Incurred     |    90    |    180    |   Total    |    FallOffDate
==============================================================
kegomez |   2012-11-19   |     2.0       |    2.0   |    2.0    |   2.0      |    2013-11-19
kegomez |   2012-11-24   |     0.5       |    0.5   |    0.5    |   2.5      |    2013-11-24
kegomez |   2013-01-21   |     2.0       |    1.0   |    0.0    |   2.5      |    2014-01-21
kegomez |   2013-08-18   |     2.0       |    2.0   |    2.0    |   4.5      |    2014-08-18
```

The total column uses values from the previous row to calculate its values. For example the date in row 4 will need to reference the date in row 3 to see if the date is greater. Would I need to try this with a subquery? How this will eventually work is that every 90 days up to 180 days the agent will loose 1 point if no more are incurred. Thus the reason why I need to reference other rows. If it helps this data is currently in Excel but is getting too large to manage and we need to move it over to something that performs better.

```
SELECT AgentID, Date, Incurred, 
    @90 := IF(Date<=CURDATE()-90 AND @r=0, Incurred-1.0, IF(Difference>90, Incurred-1, Incurred)) AS 90Day, 
    @180 := IF(Date<=CURDATE()-90 AND @r=0, Incurred-1.0, IF(Difference>180, Incurred-2, @90)) AS 180Day, 

    @Total := IF(@180<0,0,IF(FallOffDate<=CURDATE(),0, @180)) AS Total,

    FallOffDate 

FROM (SELECT  mo.AgentID, mo.Incurred, FallOffDate, 
        @r AS LEAD_date,
        DATEDIFF(@r,Date) AS Difference,
        (@r := Date) AS Date

FROM    (
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @_date = NULL
                ) VARIABLE,
                attendance m
        ORDER BY
                AgentID, Date DESC 
        ) mo
WHERE  (CASE WHEN @_date IS NULL OR @_date <> date THEN @r := NULL ELSE NULL END IS NULL)
        AND (@_date := date) IS NOT NULL) T
ORDER BY AgentID, Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do this with a subquery, try with something like this (if you want the 4th row to access the date in 3rd row):

```
SELECT  mo.AgentID, mo.date,
        @r AS 'LAG(date)',
        (case when @r<Date then 'YES' when @r is null then 'IS NULL' else 'NO' end) 'Is Bigger',
        (@r := Date) AS Date

FROM    (
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @_date = NULL
                ) variable,
                data m
        ORDER BY
                AgentID 
        ) mo
WHERE  (CASE WHEN @_date IS NULL OR @_date <> date THEN @r := NULL ELSE NULL END IS NULL)
        AND (@_date := date) IS NOT NULL
```

You can see a working demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df47/15)

Or you can try this query if you want that 3rd row has access to date in 4th row

```
SELECT AgentID,date,LEAD_date,concat(Difference,' days') FROM
(SELECT  mo.AgentID, 
        @r AS LEAD_date,
        DATEDIFF(@r,Date) as Difference,
        (@r := Date) AS Date

FROM    (
        SELECT  m.*
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @_date = NULL
                ) variable,
                data m
        ORDER BY
                AgentID,date desc 
        ) mo
WHERE  (CASE WHEN @_date IS NULL OR @_date <> date THEN @r := NULL ELSE NULL END IS NULL)
        AND (@_date := date) IS NOT NULL) T
order by AgentID,date;
```

You can see a working demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7df47/45)

Comment: I think we are on the right track here. But I think I made one slight mis-calculation. What should be happening is the date is row 3 needs to calculate the time between the date in row 4. 

I ran the test and it works great but I just think we have it backwards now.

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help.

Comment: Raul you have been a great help with this. This seems like a complex syntax. I need you help on one last trick. Now I need to Total everything on each row. How it works is the current row totals then the next row total will be the value of `@180` + that row total. Basically that total needs to reference the previous row and add the current row.

Comment: You can use something like this sqlfiddle, but adapting it for your calculated columns (and maybe some subqueries to do more advanced math stuff): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4533/18

Comment: Raul, I have been doing some experimenting with this syntax and unfortunately it isn't working as intended. For example when you first run the query data is `NULL` because the previous data is not available yet. This happens when the user logs out and then back in. The variables are undfined. My application will create a new user session.