# How to get next/previous record number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How to get previous record number in SQL Server?

Data Table:

```
Name   | SO No.
-----------------
Adrian | SO-00001
Adrian | SO-00002
Bianca | SO-00003
Carrie | SO-00004
Adrian | SO-00005
Bianca | SO-00006
Adrian | SO-00007
```

How can I get the result as below:

```
Name   | SO No.   | Previous SO
-------------------------------
Adrian | SO-00005 | SO-00002
```

Comment: Sorry that I'm a beginner. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio and add a store procedures.I didn't know what's the meaning of purely SQL. Sorry.....

Comment: I see, I have no idea how to do it purely using SQL statments, its like getting results from 2 rows and combining parts of each row to form a single row, will be interested to see whats the answer too...

Comment: You can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541451/mysql-conditions-from-multiple-rows/18543078#18543078, to a similar question

Comment: @Anmi What RDBMS are you actually using SQL Server or MySql???

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Anmi: If the problem has been solved, accept the answer that helped you most. If you have additional problem, post a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one will work the same in all major RDBMS (including SQL Server and MySql)

**UPDATED** based on your comments

```
SELECT name, 
       so_no,
       (
         SELECT MAX(so_no)
           FROM table1
          WHERE so_no < t.so_no
            AND name = t.name
       ) prev_so_no
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE so_no = 'SO-00005'
```

**SQL Server:**

**UPDATED** based on your comments

```
SELECT name, 
       MAX(so_no) so_no, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(so_no) = MIN(so_no) 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE MIN(so_no)
       END prev_so_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT TOP 2 t1.name, t1.so_no
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
      ON t1.name = t2.name
   WHERE t2.so_no = 'SO-00005'
     AND t1.so_no <= t2.so_no
   ORDER BY so_no DESC
) q
   GROUP BY name
```

if you're using **SQL Server 2012** then you can also utilize analytic function [`LAG`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)

```
SELECT name, so_no, prev_so_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT name, so_no,
         LAG(so_no, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY so_no) prev_so_no,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY so_no DESC) rnum
    FROM table1
   WHERE name = 'Adrian'
     AND so_no <= 'SO-00005'
) q
WHERE rnum = 1
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, so_no, prev_so_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT name, so_no,
         LAG(so_no, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY so_no) prev_so_no
    FROM table1
   WHERE name = 'Adrian'
     AND so_no <= 'SO-00005'
) q
 ORDER BY so_no DESC
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT name, 
       MAX(so_no) so_no, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(so_no) = MIN(so_no) 
            THEN NULL
            ELSE MIN(so_no)
       END prev_so_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT name, so_no
    FROM table1
   WHERE name = 'Adrian'
     AND so_no <= 'SO-00005'
   ORDER BY so_no DESC
   LIMIT 2
) q
   GROUP BY name
```

or

```
SELECT name, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(so_no, ',', 1) so_no,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(so_no, ',', 2), ',', -1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(so_no, ',', 1)
            THEN NULL
            ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(so_no, ',', 2), ',', -1)
       END prev_so_no
  FROM
(
  SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(so_no ORDER BY so_no DESC) so_no
    FROM table1
   WHERE name = 'Adrian'
     AND so_no <= 'SO-00005'
   GROUP BY name
) q
```

---

Output for all queries:

```
|   NAME |    SO_NO | PREV_SO_NO |
|--------|----------|------------|
| Adrian | SO-00005 |   SO-00002 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45d60/9)** demo (**SQL Server 2008**) UPDATED
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45d60/7)** demo (**SQL Server 2012**)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24b19a/18)** demo (**MySQL**)

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server 2008. If there's only one main key "SO No.", can I have the same result? Sorry for my poor English :(

Comment: @Amni I updated the topmost example. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45d60/5) for it. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Second example for SQL Server has been also updated. And corresponding sqlfiddle See at the end of the answer.

Comment: It's work now, thanks! But I've another question to get data from other column... I've update my question and build a demo on SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c47/2 Really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `offset`, this way was not so clean but perhaps can help you with

```
SELECT name as "Name",
(SELECT so_no FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Adrian%' ORDER BY so_no DESC LIMIT 1) as "SO No.", 
(SELECT so_no FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%Adrian%' ORDER BY so_no DESC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1) as "Previous SO" 
FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '%Adrian%'
LIMIT 1;
```

Sorry for bad query, kind of newbie also :(

Comment: How to modify the code if the main key is SO No. instead of Name? Actually I'm using crystal report, is it better/possible to get result by more than 1 store procedures?

Comment: I see, I'll try to edit it using subquery inside subquery, however, have you try @peterm solution? perhaps it can give you better answer while I try to research it more.

Comment: For the Crystal Report thing, is this on `VB.net`? Actually using more than 1 SP is ok, like calling another function or SP inside other function or SP. is it what you meant?