# How to get next/previous record number? (Part 2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the [solution from @peterm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691444) 
and it works.

But I've another question, how can I get result as below:

```
  Name   | SO No.   | Previous SO | Previous SO Details
  ---------------------------------------------------
  Adrian | SO-00005 | SO-00002    | details SO-00002
```

Sample of data:

```
Name   | SO No.   | SO Details
------------------------------------
Adrian | SO-00001 | details SO-00001
Adrian | SO-00002 | details SO-00002
Bianca | SO-00003 | details SO-00003
Carrie | SO-00004 | details SO-00004
Adrian | SO-00005 | details SO-00005
Bianca | SO-00006 | details SO-00006
Adrian | SO-00007 | details SO-00007
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c47/2)

Comment: Where is the previous so details field?

Comment: In same table column named as "details". Here's is the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c47/2

Comment: Sorry I've modified my question and I've forgot to mark down what result I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one way to achieve this:

```
with CTE_table_1 as(
  select name
       , so_no
       , details
       , row_number() over(partition by name 
                           order by so_no) as rn
    from table1
  )
select name
     , so_no
     , (select max(so_no)
          from cte_table_1 q
         where q.rn = s.rn - 1 -- here you can regulate how far back you want to go 
           and s.name = q.name) as prev_so_no
     , details
     , (select max(details)
          from cte_table_1 q
         where q.rn = s.rn - 1
           and s.name = q.name) as prev_details
  from cte_table_1 s
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo #1*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c47/32)

[*SQLFiddle Demo #2*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03c47/53)

Comment: Sorry I've modified my question. And there's a main key "SO No." only

Answer (score 0):

in Sql Server 2012 new feature is add which called window functions lag and lead .
They can show your previous or the next result of aggregate functions.
;)

Comment: Thank you for your replied. As I'm using SQL server 2008 and didn't have this function

Comment: My idea is that you should declare a temporary table to keep the previous result , and in a while loop the cursor value is 1 less than the main while cursor. then you can show previous.